# Nginx: rewrite for subdomain to folder AND files inside it

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have nginx rewrite rule - it redirects all subdomain requests from sub to folder:

```
server {
listen      77.77.77.77:80;
server_name domaincom *.domaincom;

root /home/admin/web/domaincom/public_html/subs/$subdomain;
set $subdomain "";
if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.domaincom$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
    #rewrite $request_uri $1.$request_uri;
    #rewrite ^(.*txt)$ $subdomain.$request_uri;   just testing here
#rewrite ^(.*\.txt)$ $subdomain.$request_uri/$1;

}
if ($host ~* ^www.domaincom$) {
    set $subdomain "";
}

 # location $subdomain {
    # # # An example rewrite
    # rewrite ^/(.*txt)$ $request_uri;
# }

index       index.php;
access_log  off;
error_log /dev/null;


location / {

root        /home/admin/web/domaincom/public_html;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

error_page  403 /error/404.html;
error_page 404 = @foobar;

location @foobar {
return 301 /;
}
error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domaincom/document_errors/;
}

                # Access deny for bots
# See bots list in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
if ($limit_bots = 1) {
          return 403;
    }


location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}

location /vstats/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domaincom/stats/;
    include /home/admin/conf/web/domaincom.auth*;
}

include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

include     /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.domaincom.conf*;
}
```

It work well, but i have one problem.

And in domain and subdomains i have a same php-script that gets data from txt file, like this:

```
file(key.txt);
```

My php-fpm module, i think, doesn't know about nginx rules and gets data in SUB from ROOT domain - it's wrong. 
Please help me to add nginx exceptions or add rule to get txt's data in SUB from SUBs. Not_from_root_domain. Thanks.

Comment: When i request key.txt - it gets from root domain, not subdomain

Comment: Have you tried using `__DIR__` constant, e.g. `file( __DIR__ . 'key.txt' )`?

Comment: Thanks. it's a good idea, but doesn't work, i've checked. When i just manually open in browser: `http://subdomain.domaincom/key.txt` - it opens `http://domaincom/key.txt` (there is `subdomain.domaincom` with `key.txt` from root domain in browser adress). It rewrites strongly.

Comment: Can you post your whole `server` block?

Comment: Sure. I can add it here in comments, so i've added in https://pastebin.com/1Qn3MSj6

Comment: First you define your root as `/home/admin/web/domaincom/public_html/subs/$subdomain` at `server { ... }` level, and then you redefine it as `/home/admin/web/domaincom/public_html` at `location / { ... }` level, making nginx ignoring your first `root` directive.

Comment: BTW, there is much better ways to set an expiration time headers. There is no need in these nested locations at all. What nginx version do you have?

Comment: nginx/1.14.2
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some optimizations of your config:

1) Defining your subdomain root with the help of `map` directive:

```
map $http_host $root_suffix {
    ~^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ "";
    ~^(.+)\.domain\.com$ /subs/$1;
}
```

2) Defining expire time based on request URI suffix:

```
map $uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~*.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ max;
}
```

(This `map` directives must be defined **outside** the `server { }` block, at the `http { }` context level.)

Now your `server { }` block:

```
server {
    listen      77.77.77.77:80;
    server_name .domaincom;
    root        /home/admin/web/domaincom/public_html$root_suffix;
    expires     $expires;

    index       index.php;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   /dev/null;

    # your locations here
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Everything works as expected?

Comment: There is a problem: i must define `map` directive in `http` section, but in your solution domain.com (one domain) defined. But in my configuration i have different configs for each domain and one main nginx.conf (with `http`). I have to use `map`, but i can to do it only in main config... Is there regex or something like that for each_domain in `map` and `http`?

Comment: I don't see any problems, put `map` directives into the same file where `domaincom` is defined, but before the `server` block.

Comment: Also, do you know, how to add `?mydomain\.com$` into Vesta control panel default config? There is template and domains looks like `server_name %domain_idn% %alias_idn%;` - but in my `map` section (according to your solution) i should to backslash the `.` dots.

Comment: I think this is too complex configuration for a template to be created for it. `^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$` is a regex matches only `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`, all other subdomains does not match this regex and falls to the second one. `.domain.com` is a special nginx [server name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) form which matches `domain.com` and `*.domain.com` (note that server name `*.domain.com` matches `www.domain.com` and any other subdomain under `domain.com`, but not a `domain.com` itself).